# How to write a view that that responds with the http request that the function is passed?

Tags: django, django-views

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from testform import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.testhandler),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def testhandler(request):
    #return HttpResponse(request)
```

In views.py how to return the request that testhandler is passed?

Comment: i mean a view that displays http request

Comment: why would you want to display the `request` ?

Comment: I just wanted to see what is going on. I think it might be useful while debugging to know exactly where something broke.

Comment: The right way to do it would be to use django debug toolbars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit this is the weirdest question I have ever seen on SO. Anyway you can get the view return the `request` like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def testhandler(request):
    return HttpResponse(request.__str__())
```

If you want to see it a bit nicer in browser, you can try:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def testhandler(request):
    return HttpResponse('<br />'.join(request.__str__().split('\n'))) # convert \n to <br />
```

Comment: why is the response displaying both GET and POST? is it possible for the request to be both GET and POST at the same time?

Comment: by the way, thanks for your response. that was really helpful.

Comment: You should read more about the `request` object here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects, that GET and POST you see are attributes of this object. Feel free to accept my answer if it helps